# AWS VPC VPN IPsec to customer gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to make a VPN IPsec connection between customer gateway and aws virtual private gateway. The tunnels status is up. But,  when I'm doing ping from customer's subnet to VPC's subnet - nothing happens. Does anyone know why ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have done these things:

- Have you configured the routes in your AWS VPC network? Write the IP range of your peer VPC and link it to the Virtual Cloud Gateway.
- Have you specified the firewall rules in AWS (via the security groups of the VMs - allow ingress ICMP protocol to all ports). Have you also configured the firewall rules on your peer VPC to allow egress ICMP protocol?